# Easiest way of porting data into a database

Tags: ms-access, import

Recently, I received a lot of information from one of my friends who made a quiz type program.  He asked me to help port it into an Access database.

His program places all the info in a grid; around 3000 fields full of info, and we need to port it over to Access.

Is there a program that will read field-by-field and insert the data into Access, and then automatically continue to the next field?

The grid also has a copy button, but it copyies everything without grid, so every line looks kinda like this:

`Info1:herestheinfo Info2:herestheinfo`, and so on, is there any easy way of porting this to an Access database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Access' built-in import features to import data from just about any source.

For Access 2007, the "ribbon" menu has an "External Data" tab, where you can select "Text".

[image]

From there it is pretty simple to import text-based data.  As you can see from the screenshot, there are a number of other types of data you can import.